# No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo "string"

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código en c# con una enumeración y lo recorro con un for. Le convertí a byte la enumeración en el mismo for para poder compararlo y tengo error al ingresar el valor de la opción que quiero ver:

El error de la linea esta marcado

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu de opciones: ");

            Menu opcion;

            for(opcion = 0; (byte)opcion <=2; opcion++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}) {1}", opcion.GetHashCode(), opcion.ToString());

            }


            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una opcion: ");
             //aqui esta el error en el Console.ReadLine
             opcion = Covert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());
    
            switch (opcion)
            {

                case Menu.Alta:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingresar nombre para dar de alta");
                    break;
                case Menu.Baja:
                    Console.WriteLine("Seleccionar nombre para eliminar");
                    break;
                case Menu.Modificacion:
                    Console.WriteLine("Seleccionar nombre para modificar");
                    break;
            }
             
            





        }
```

Comment: Que es la clase Menu? donde falla la conversion?

Comment: la clase menu es una enumeracion, en el ciclo for lo converti a byte y para ingresar el dato para que pueda leerlo tambien pero marca error

Comment: `Covert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());` debería se `Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());` es decir, Convert en vez de Covert, falta una `n`

Comment: le aregue la n pero de todas formas no funciona

Comment: Nos mostrs como esta definida la enumeracion? porque es raro que la transformes a byte, cuando es int...

Comment: enum Menu
    {
        Alta,
        Baja,
        Modificacion
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Castea al tipo Menu y corrige la llamada a Convert* con "n"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Menu de opciones: ");

        Menu opcion;

        for (opcion = 0; (byte)opcion <= 2; opcion++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}) {1}", opcion.GetHashCode(), opcion.ToString());

        }


        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una opcion: ");
        //aqui esta el error en el Console.ReadLine
        opcion = (Menu)Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (opcion)
        {

            case Menu.Alta:
                Console.WriteLine("Ingresar nombre para dar de alta");
                break;
            case Menu.Baja:
                Console.WriteLine("Seleccionar nombre para eliminar");
                break;
            case Menu.Modificacion:
                Console.WriteLine("Seleccionar nombre para modificar");
                break;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tendrias que caster la opcion al tipo del `enum`

```
var temp = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());
opcion = (Menu)temp;
```

Algo como esto

```
    using System;
                    
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu de opciones: ");

            Menu opcion;

            for(opcion = 0; (byte)opcion <=2; opcion++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}) {1}", opcion.GetHashCode(), opcion.ToString());

            }


            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una opcion: ");
            //aqui esta el error en el Console.ReadLine
            var temp = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());
            opcion = (Menu)temp;
            
            switch (opcion)
            {

                case Menu.Alta:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingresar nombre para dar de alta");
                    break;
                case Menu.Baja:
                    Console.WriteLine("Seleccionar nombre para eliminar");
                    break;
                case Menu.Modificacion:
                    Console.WriteLine("Seleccionar nombre para modificar");
                    break;
            }
                 
        }
        
        enum Menu{
            Alta = 0,
            Baja = 1,
            Modificacion = 2
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias! pero la variable opcion debe ser del tipo menu asi como anteriormente lo tenia

Comment: entiendo, edite el codigo para resolver ese punto